# Why are the free tiers for Cloud Functions for Firebase and Cloud Functions different?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

On the pricing page for [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/), it says that the Spark (free) plan has a limit of 125K invocations, 40K GB-seconds and 40K CPU-seconds per month, and only outbound networking for Google services. This is considerably different than the pricing for [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing) pricing where you get 2M invocations, 400K GB-seconds, 400K CPU-seconds and 5GB of outbound networking per month. Why are these two free tiers different when Cloud Functions for Firebase is basically thin a wrapper for Cloud Functions?
This is mostly a separate question, but still related: Am I able to use native Cloud Functions with Firebase from the linked Google Cloud Platform project? I ask because Firebase projects still have a linked Google Cloud Platform project so I was wondering if I could use the Google Cloud Platform free tier for Cloud Functions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please contact Firebase support for questions about billing. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: Also, if you have two different questions, please ask them separately.  This will increase your chances of getting a correct answer to each one, as folks here might not be able to answer both correctly.

Comment: Reading the firebase pricing page Alex if you hover over the ? you will see you get the same quota as GCP as long as you are on the blaze plan. `...On the Blaze plan, Cloud Functions provides a perpetual free tier. The first 2,000,000 invocations, 400,000 GB-sec, 200,000 CPU-sec, and 5 GB of Internet egress traffic is provided for free each month. You are only charged on usage past this free allotment.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer this. However, I am not the product manager for either product family so this is just my opinion working with Google and often talking shop with them.

Google Firebase is a different product with a different target audience compared to Google Cloud. Firebase is a great serverless solution. The revenue that Google can generate from Firebase is less than the possibly larger, more complex cloud solutions. Therefore, I would expect the Firebase free offering to consist of less than a full cloud offering. In regards to why certain decisions are made, most companies will not answer these types of questions. Marketing decision are generally considered private information on a need-to-know basis.

For your second question.

Firebase functions are Google Cloud Functions. You can use the free tier from Google Cloud provided that you also have a Google Cloud account. However, if you are invoking Functions from Firebase services, then Firebase usage discounts apply to that subset.